# How to prevent passing celery task arguments to the logs?

Tags: python, logging, celery, python-logging

I have a celery task that takes an avro file as a byte string and writes it to a database. This task is taken up by a worker and it succeeds as I can see it in the database.

However, the worker's logs are cluttered with the byte string argument that the task takes.
[Here is how the log looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCHH9.png)

I have a INFO level log message that would say how many seconds it took for the data to be written to the database, but I cant see it as the byte string makes it impossible to read the logs.

A root logger was configured with [these fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzUkL.png)

But celery adds the "data" field, where "arg" contains the huge byte string. (Refer 1st screenshot)

How do I configure celery to NOT add the task's arguments in the logs? Any help on this would be appreciated.

I read the documentation and referred other posts. But none have a conclusive answer.